# Android app crashed after installing via adb

Tags: android, crash, apk, adb, ionos

I would like to capture the traffic of the IONOS App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oneandone.ciso.mobile.app.android&hl=de&gl=US).
The reason is simple: I need the API to configure my server and the support told me that i have to find it out by myself.

So I modified the apk and after the login it crashed, never had this behaviour before...

**I tried to install the original apk file and it also crashed. (adb install <name.spk>)**
(yes, i turned of signature verification for apps installed via usb.)

**Any ideas how I could figure out the reason the this issue?

Other apks I could install this way without any problems.**

Thanks for your help
Max

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Having a similar problem